# How to draw the simplest grid map OpenGL 1.0

Tags: opengl, tilemap, maps

I want to draw a simple black & white grid map, like that:
[image]

I have been searching for a way to generate tile, a tile map and tho and I want to draw this map and thats all. I mean that I want to draw it only once so it should be easy.
I use OpenGL 1.0. How can I draw that and how should I draw - should I draw an Image and place it  like a map, should I draw a tile and multiple it ?

Comment: Are you sure you are and want to be using OpenGL 1.0? There have been many releases [since 1992](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL). Assuming you're working on an old version with immediate-mode rendering: Have you considered `glBegin(GL_LINES)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, OpenGL 1.0 is **very** outdated. What you probably mean is, that you are using immediate mode. If you are still learning, I strongly suggest to adapt to modern OpenGL ASAP. Immediate mode is inefficient, as every time you draw a vertex, you have to do a driver/GL call, which is very expensive.

So, if you insist on doing it the immediate way, the simplest way I can think of is to:

1. Set viewport size and eventually clear the screen to black and a blank depth buffer
2. Load an identity matrix (no transformation)
3. Begin an immediate draw block
4. Draw vertical lines using coloured vertices.
5. Draw horizontal lines as well.
6. End the draw block and swap the front and back buffer if you are using a double buffered context.

   ```
   glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
   glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //RGBA
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   glLoadIdentity();

   glBegin(GL_LINES);
   glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f); // White (RGB)
   for( float x = 0; x < windowWidth; x += lineHDistance )
   {
       glVertex3f(x, 0.0f, 0.0f);
       glVertex3f(x, float(windowHeight), 0.0f);
   }
   for( float y = 0; y < windowHeight; y += lineVDistance )
   {
       glVertex3f(0.0f, y, 0.0f);
       glVertex3f(float(windowWidth), y, 0.0f);
   }
   glEnd();

   wglSwapBuffers(); // Windows-way to swap buffers
   ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Helped me alot, First I now work on LibGDX and it's fantastic! Thank you very much!